# load script using jquery ajax and remove based on change of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-api

I am adding a google api script using jquery ajax, based on the language `lang` chosen by the user inside the app:

```
var src = '';
if (lang == 'en') {
    src = 'https://script1.googleapis.com/script1';
} else {
    src = 'https://script2.googleapis.com/script2';
}
jQuery.ajax({
    url: src,
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function () {
    },
    async: true
});
```

Once this is added, when the user changes the language, the second script gets added to the page, and I get this error:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

How can I remove the old script once the language is changed? so that each time the script corresponding to the chosen language of the site is loaded?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once a script is loaded, the objects and functions it defines are kept in memory.
The best you can do is to is to remove it globally like `delete window.ga` and load again your script.

and if you about the duplication of script on the dom just remove it before calling the next script.

Comment: after src= ''; add delete window.ga

Comment: i am a newbie, can you please tell me how it should look like exactly thanks